# How to parse values of a set from a table?

Tags: sql, select, set

In a table I have a column called **Categories**, which is a set, and has variable values, there are no rows in the column, so I am not trying to parse the values in the rows, I parse the values from this set directly, how can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is tough to understand, please provide some data and such so it gets easier. Take yourself time to ask and the answers will improve.

Comment: "*there are no rows in the column*". Of course there are none. Rows are "in" a table, never "in" a column.

Comment: Assume there is an empty table, there are only empty column, so no rows, one of the columns, 'Categories' in this case, is a set and the set has values, how can I parse those values?

Comment: Even after your comments I still have no idea what you are trying to do. Most likely your or mine English is broken. Add Your Code and help will occur.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, you have a table in which one of the columns is of a set type. This is not conventional and not recommended. Tables are sets themselves. Try remodeling the table  by splitting it in two: one with the columns you already have minus Categories ; and a Category table to keep each element of all sets, associated with a foreign key. Now there would be no need for parsing.

Of course, this is not a valid solution if you cannot make such a change.

Comment: Yep I think you understood me. Anyhow even if not conventional, I couldn't find an answer to how the set values can be parsed. Any idea?

Comment: This solution doesn't involve parsing at all, but making the database more adequate to your purpose. I wouldn't even be able to know how to parse something I'm not aware of, in this case what you called a set. If you put your code that builds the table in your question, I will be glad to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this does what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Categories FROM (Table)
```

Comment: I have this already and it only parses the 'selected' values from the set in each particular row. I would like to parse the values from the set itself regardless if there are rows or not.

Comment: @acidking Afaik there is no 'SET' in Sql that has a meaning that would match into your sentence. I'm quite sure that word is not what you mean.